# SQL show result if meta_key not exists or not is 1

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, metadata

with the following SQL query I check whether a meta value of a (Wordress) post is not equal to 1. But I also want to check if the meta_key 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' exists. And if it not exists I still want to select the `ID`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m2 ON m2.post_id = p.ID
AND m2.meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded'
AND m2.meta_value != 1
```

So my query needs to do the following checks:

- Select the results where meta_key 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' is not
  equal to 1.
- And also if the meta_key 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' not exists.

I tried it with a LEFT JOIN, but the problem is that if the meta_value of meta_key 'gtp_conversion_uploaded' is equal to 1, I still get results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m2 ON m2.post_id = p.ID 
                        AND m2.meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded'
WHERE m2.meta_key is null 
OR m2.meta_value != 1
```

Comment: Why not make `m2.meta_key is null` condition as JOIN condition like `m2.meta_key is null OR m2.meta_key = 'gtp_conversion_uploaded'`

Comment: @Rahul that is Bad habits

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar, and why so ...?